# LIKE operator in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Is there any way to code this in snowflake?

Table 1

[image]

Based on look up table's DEPT, I want to have values like below in main table

[image]

This means, when it is SALES INTERNAL and then extra texts it should take the value of "SALES INTERNAL" as data access.

Below code produces duplicates.

```
ON LOWER (LTRIM(RTRIM(nvl(MainTable."DEPT", 'NA')))) ilike  LOWER (LTRIM(RTRIM(nvl(LookUpTable."DEPT,'NA')))||'%')
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I think you may want to be more prescriptive in this logic - because if you are looking to use substrings of existing data values for access, I already see an issue since "SALES" provides a lookup access for ALL, and "SALES" is also present as a substring in "SALES INTERNAL" ... which has a restricted lookup access.

Comment: I think it would be helpful to have exact input and output sample tables (preferably in text and even better as a create table / insert statement to give people a head start). As currently shown it's not clear how to get from the input to the output.